# How best to store objectID from MongoDB in id element

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb

I am creating an application for managing drive records. I also use a NoSQL Mongo database. For example, I have such a record in MongoDtb:

```
_id: ObjectID(638482630149fa962e34ee1c)
driver: "John Defoe"
car: "Ferrari"
startDrive: 2022-11-13T00:00:00.000+00:00
endDrive: 2022-11-15T00:00:00.000+00:00
__v: 0
```

I want to delete the given record when I click the delete button that I create in HTML. What is the best way to achieve deletion from the database after clicking a button?

It occurred to me to asynchronously create individual driving records and create a button for them to delete the given record. Assign id = ObjectId from database to each button.

Then I catch the button click, find its id and delete the record based on the id.

With this procedure, I don't know if it's a good idea to insert the id from the database on the frontend.

I don't know if it is correct to store the id from the database in the id element.

Functionally, everything works for me, I just don't know if it's the right procedure and I would like to ask more experienced developers what procedure they choose.

Answer (score 0):

Using this api, you can delete an element in mongodb by specifying its id and this is a professional solution

```js
router.delete('/:id', async(req, res)=> {
    const IDs = req.params.id
    await Transaction.deleteOne({ _id: IDs})
        res.json({'message': 'Delete Operation successfull'})
})
```